# A Neural Network in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am new to latex, wanted to draw these diagrams for the background section of my thesis. Could get the snapshot but doesn't look good. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second two diagrams are extremely simple. Start with the TikZ manual, which has plenty of tutorials. When you have something working, post a real question with a minimal document with the diagram code asking for help with the parts you can't quite get.

Comment: Of course we will serve you without seeing any code as your effort. Or perhaps you made some code lines which you can post as your current status?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a starting point for the first one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\tikzset{
  redondo/.style={
    draw=blue,
    line width=1pt,
    rounded corners=3pt,
    text width=#1
  },
  punto/.style={
    fill=red,
    circle,
    inner sep=1.25pt
  },
  tresp/.pic={
    \node[punto] at (0.25,0) {};
    \node[punto] at (0.5,0) {};
    \node[punto] at (0.75,0) {};
  },
  dosp/.pic={
    \node[punto] at (0.25,0) {};
    \node[punto] at (0.5,0) {};
  },
  cuadra/.style={
    fill=teal,
    minimum size=10pt
  },
  arr/.style={
    line width=1pt,
    draw=green!70!black,
    ->,
    >=latex
  }  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm and 1cm]
\node[redondo=7cm]
  (upper)
  {};
\pic at (upper.west) {tresp};
\pic at (upper.center) {dosp};
\pic at ([xshift=-1cm]upper.east) {tresp};
\node[] 
  at ([yshift=-1pt]$ (upper.center)!0.5!(upper.west) $ ) {$\ldots$};
\node[] 
  at ([yshift=-1pt]$ (upper.center)!0.5!(upper.east) $ ) {$\ldots$};

\node[redondo=5cm,below=of upper]
  (middle)
  {};
\pic at (middle.west) {tresp};
\pic at ([xshift=-0.75cm]middle.east) {dosp};
\node[] at ([xshift=4pt,yshift=-1pt]middle) {$\ldots$};

\node[redondo=2cm,below=of middle,anchor=east,xshift=-30pt,label={20:$C(w_{t-n+1})$}]
  (lowermiddle)
  {};
\node[redondo=2cm,below=of middle,anchor=west,xshift=30pt,label={10:$C(w_{t-n+1})$}]
  (lowerright)
  {};
\node[redondo=2cm,left=of lowermiddle,label={above left:$C(w_{t-n+1})$}]
  (lowerleft)
  {};

\foreach \Valor/\NodeLabel in {left/n+1,middle/2,right/1/}
{
  \pic at (lower\Valor.west) {tresp};
  \pic at ([xshift=-0.75cm]lower\Valor.east) {dosp};
  \node[cuadra,below=of lower\Valor,label={below:{index for $w_{t-\NodeLabel}$}}] (cuadra\Valor) {};
  \node[] at ([xshift=4pt,yshift=-1pt]lower\Valor) {$\ldots$};
}

\draw[arr,dashed] 
  (lowerleft) to[out=92,in=210] ([xshift=10pt]upper.south west);
\draw[arr,dashed] 
  (lowermiddle) to[out=150,in=210] ([xshift=-50pt]upper.south);
\draw[arr,dashed] 
  (lowerright) to[out=30,in=-30] ([xshift=50pt]upper.south);
\foreach \Valor in {left,middle,right}
{
    \draw[arr] (cuadra\Valor) -- coordinate (aux\Valor) (lower\Valor);
}
\foreach \Valor/\Angulo in {left/186,middle/193,right/350}
{
    \draw[arr] (lower\Valor) -- (middle.\Angulo);
}
\draw[arr] (middle) -- (upper);
\draw[arr] 
  (upper) -- 
  ++(0pt,1cm) node[above] {$i-$th output};
\draw[<->,magenta,dashed,>=latex]
  (auxleft) -- 
  ++(20pt,-10pt) --
  ([shift={(-20pt,-10pt)}]auxright) coordinate[pos=0.5] (auxc) --
  (auxright);
\draw[->,magenta,dashed,>=latex]
  (auxc) -- (auxmiddle);
\node[anchor=south west] 
  at (auxc) {Matrix $C$};    
\node[anchor=north west,align=left] 
  at (auxc) {shared parameters \\ across words};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the second one; using this you can easily create the remaining one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,calc}

\tikzset{
  arro/.style={
    ->,
    >=latex
  },
  bloque/.style={
    draw,
    minimum height=1cm,
    minimum width=0.5cm
  }  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[]
  (input)
  {Input};
\node[bloque,below=of input,label={left:$w(t-2)$}]
  (inputi)
  {};
\node[bloque,below=of inputi,label={left:$w(t-1)$}]
  (inputii)
  {};
\coordinate[below=of inputii] (aux);  
\node[bloque,below=of aux,label={left:$w(t+1)$}]
  (inputiii)
  {};
\node[bloque,below=of inputiii,label={left:$w(t+2)$}]
  (inputiv)
  {};

\node[right=of input]
  (proje)
  {Projection};
\node[bloque,label={above:\textsc{sum}}]
  at (proje|-aux)
  (projei)
  {};

\node[right=of proje]
  (out)
  {Output};
\node[bloque,label={right:$w(t)$}]
  at (out|-aux)
  (outi)
  {};

\foreach \Valor in {i,ii,iii,iv}
{
  \draw[arro] (input\Valor) -- (projei);
}  
\draw[arro] (projei) -- (outi);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]